# Chunk uploading directly to s3 jquery-file-upload, only last chunk is saved

Tags: jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3, blueimp

I am using the [Blueimp/jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin for uploading files to AWS S3 directly from JS client code. I used multipart upload. Here is setup of fileupload:

`multipart: true,
maxChunkSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
autoUpload: true,`

When I log responses with this event listener: `'fileuploadchunkdone'` I can see that all chunks uploaded as well, but in the bucket only last chunk is saved. Also when I watch my bucket during uploading I can see that the file size is equal chunk size, but after upload complete size of the file equals last chunk size, and file is corrupted.

Am i doing wrong something? Or this is some bug?

Here is my S3 settings:

CORS:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Range</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Disposition</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-meta-qqfilename</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-date</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Thanks for help!

Update:

Here is js code that i use for this:

```
$('.upload-video-part').each(function(){
  var that = this;
  var videoId;
  $(this).fileupload({
    sequentialUploads: true,
    multipart: true,
    disableValidation: true,
    maxChunkSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    autoUpload: true,
    add: function (event, data) {
      $(that).find('input[type=file]').hide();
      $(that).find('#progress').show();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/uploaded_videos",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {doc: {title: data.files[0].name}},
        async: false,
        success: function(retdata) {
          $(that).find('input[name=key]').val(retdata.key);
          $(that).find('input[name=policy]').val(retdata.policy);
          $(that).find('input[name=signature]').val(retdata.signature);
          $(that).parent().append('<div id="video-edit-form-' + retdata.id + '"></div>');
          videoId = retdata.id;
          data.submit();
          $.get({
            url: "/edit_after_upload?id=" + videoId,
            success: function(data) {
              $('#edit_uploaded_video_' + retdata.id).submit(function(e, data){
                e.preventDefault();
                var messageArea = $('#edit_uploaded_video_' + retdata.id).find('.message-area')[0];
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'PUT',
                  url: $('#edit_uploaded_video_' + retdata.id).attr('action'),
                  data: $('#edit_uploaded_video_' + retdata.id).serialize(),
                  success: function(data) {
                    $(messageArea).css('color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .5');
                    messageArea.innerHTML = 'Video was successfuly saved!';
                    $(messageArea).css('display', 'inline-block');
                  },
                  error: function(err){
                    $(messageArea).css('color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .5');
                    messageArea.innerHTML = err.responseJSON.errors;
                    $(messageArea).css('display', 'inline-block');
                  }
                });
                return false;
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    },
    send: function(e, data) {},
    fail: function(e, data) {
      $(that).find('.fileinput-button span')[0].innerHTML = 'Video uploading failed';
      $(that).find('#progress .bar').css('background', 'red');
    },
    done: function (event, data) {
      $(that).find('.fileinput-button span')[0].innerHTML = 'Video successfully uploaded';
      $(that).find('#progress .bar').css('background', 'green');
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      $(that).find('#progress .bar').css( 'width', progress + '%');
    }
  }).on('fileuploadchunksend', function (e, data) {});
});
```

Comment: This definitely would not be CORS related.

Comment: S3 does not throw an error if you upload the same part *number* more than once and they differ, so the symptoms you describe would be the exact expected behavior if you had a bug that caused you to tell the API that you were uploading part 1, then part 1, then part 1, then part 1, ... calling each part "part 1" in the API request rather than part *n*, then sending an completion request with only the metadata from the last part you sent... which would be a serious defect in either your code or the library you are using.

Comment: What library is this, exactly?  I can't find evidence of the library I thought you were using actually doing an S3 multipart upload.  Links to docs you are working from, and your own code edited into the question may be needed.

Comment: Michael, i use [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). And i am not sure if i can set the number of each chunk.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems I initially made some incorrect assumptions about exactly what you were trying to do.  S3 has a [multipart upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) that allows you to upload each "chunk" (which doesn't refer to chunked encoding) using part numbers, and when you're done, you send back the etag of each uploaded part and S3 combines them into one object... which isn't what you are doing.  It's not readily apparent to me whether what you are doing is within the design intentions of that module and S3's interface.  Please show your code.

Comment: Michael, i updated question. There is my code now. Thank you for explaining, but i am not sure how should i configure headers in this case? I had ETag headers in responses for each chunk, but what should i do with them?

Comment: Hi @shatskiym
I'm also facing same issue.
Please let me know if you solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: @shatskiym have you found a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

To upload file in multiple chunks in s3. First Create Multi Part Upload with s3 api.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html

From this api you will receive Upload id.

Then use this api to upload parts provide partNumber and upload id in the data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html#API_UploadPart_RequestSyntax

Use etag and partNumber receive from this api to complete partUpload with API_CompleteMultipartUpload

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html

Comment: Please can you provide the code solution too?